# How should I solve Attribute and Import errors generated on using py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have created an exe file using py2exe, however it gives me an Attribute error and an import error on execution. I have used urllib2 and BeautifulSoup in my main script, which is abc.py

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['abc.py'])
options={"py2exe": {'includes': ["BeautifulSoup"]}}
```

I have added the 'includes' parameter after referring to another question on this website. It however doesn't work for me.

The output I get from abc.exe is

> C:\Users\Dhruv Mullick\Desktop\dist>abc.exe Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\boot_common.py", line 92, in
>   
>       import linecache   File "linecache.pyc", line 9, in    File "os.pyc", line 398, in    File "UserDict.pyc", line 83,
>   in    File "_abcoll.pyc", line 11, in    File
>   "abc.pyc", line 3, in    File "bs4__init__.pyc", line 30, in
>      File "bs4\builder__init__.pyc", line 1, in    File
>   "collections.pyc", line 6, in  AttributeError: 'module' object
>   has no attribute '**all**' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "abc.py", line 3, in    File "bs4__init__.pyc", line 26, in
>      File "os.pyc", line 398, in    File "UserDict.pyc",
>   line 83, in    File "_abcoll.pyc", line 11, in    File
>   "abc.pyc", line 3, in  ImportError: cannot import name
>   BeautifulSoup
>
> C:\Users\Dhruv Mullick\Desktop\dist>

Answer (score 0):

Your script 'abc.py' conflicts with the abc module in Python's standardlibrary.
Rename the script to something else (maybe abc_app.py), adapt the setup-script and rebuild.

You should also make sure to remove any 'abc.pyc' or 'abc.pyo' files which you may have.  And remove the 'build' directory that py2exe creates...